# Notation for the coefficient of the $i$th term of formal power series.

Tags: ring-theory, notation, power-series

What notation is standard for the coefficient of $X^i$ in a formal power series $P$? I was thinking of $X^i \bullet P$, by analogy with the dot product.

Comment: What's bad about $\,a_i\,$ ...? And why do you want to relate this to some inner product (which one and over what linear space)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One notation used is $[X^i]P$.  According to [Knuth, arXiv:9402216v1](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9402216), this was introduced by I. P. Goulden and D. M. Jackson in their book *Combinatorial Enumeration* (Wiley, 1983) on p. 1.